# Almost everywhere differentiable functions: what can we do? Integration by parts?

Tags: integration, derivatives, riemann-integration, riemann-sum, almost-everywhere

Let $A$ be an open measurable set and $A_0$ is a subset of $A$ which has measure zero.

Let $g$ and $f$ be almost everywhere differentiable function defined on $A$.

What is the impact of "almost everywhere"? What do I need to watch out for?

For example can we still use integration by parts and write

$$\int_A f(x) g^{\prime}(x) d x=f(x) g(x)- \int_A f^{\prime}(x) g(x) d x$$

Or for example, since $f$ is a.e. differentiable we know that it is also a.e. continuous, therefore do we still have the convergence of the Riemann sum to the Riemann integral, i.e.

$$\int_a^b f(x) d x= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{ i = 1 }^n f( a+i \Delta x) \Delta x$$

where $a,b \in A$ and can be such that $a, b \in A_0$

Comment: Yes you can integrate by parts.

Comment: A function is Riemann Integrable on a bounded interval if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere. However, you know that $f$ and $g$ are continuous a.e., but you do not know that $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous a.e.. Therefore you also do not know if $fg'$ or $gf'$ are continuous a.e.. Thus you do not know that $fg'$ or $gf'$ are Riemann integrable. Without that additional condition, you'll have to resort to stronger Lesbegue or Henstock-Kurzweil integration.